# Using child processes to calculate an unknown array

Tags: c

I am trying to split the roles of the child processes to calculate the sum of an array, but I got blocked and didn't know how to do it.
Here's what I did so far :
I made a for loop that creates child processes, and a pipe for each child to later send the data through the pipe to the parent to calculate the total sum

```
void genWorkers(char **numbers, int pfd[][2], size_t numberOfLines, size_t nChilds)
{
    pid_t c;
    int offset = 0;
    int arrSize = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(int);
    int count = 0;

    //Generate nChilds
    for (int i = 0; i < nChilds; i++)
    {
        if (pipe(pfd[i]) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s", "Unable to create a pipe\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        c = fork();

        if (c == 0)
        {
            int sum = childSum(numbers, count, arrSize); // Blocked here
            count++;
            if (count == numberOfLines)
                break;
            close(pfd[i][0]);                    // Close unused read end
            write(pfd[i][1], &sum, sizeof(sum)); //Write to the parent process (Through the pipe)
            close(pfd[i][1]);                    // Close write pipe and send it to the reader
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
}
```

childSum :

```
int childSum(char **numbers, int offset, int count)
{
    int sum = 0;

    if (numbers == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    for (int i = offset; i < count; i++)
    {
        sum += sumOfDigits(*(numbers + i));
    }

    return sum;
}
```

How do I distribute the roles of the CHILD PROCESSES here, especially if I don't have a fixed number of childs or arrays (This is the part that confused/blocked me the most).

Then, to accumulate all the sums, I created this function:

```
int collectResults(int pfd[][2], size_t nChilds)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int n;

    for (int i = 0; i < nChilds; i++)
    {
        close(pfd[i][1]); //Close unused write end
        read(pfd[i][0], &n, sizeof(n));
        sum += n;

        close(pfd[i][0]);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: The childs doesn't have any task code to do? They only wait?

Comment: You mean the parent ?

Comment: Hello @Gaston, no, the parent does his job when c=0, but for the others fork ids (your childs), they doesn't have nothing to do (your else case is empty). Also, This `collectResults()` is called on parent process?  Answering your last question, unfortunately you need to know CHILD PROCESSES in order to collect  all data, for that save `nChilds` somewhere  after calling `genWorkers()`

Comment: @bmalbusca the child does his job when c = 0 not the parent . The parent will have to wait the child to finish his job . `Upon successful completion, fork() returns a value of 0 to the child process and returns the process ID of the child process to the parent process`